# Why the variable containing reference to an object can't be echoed in PHP? Why the output of object and reference is same after var_dump()?

Tags: php, class, oop, object, var-dump

I've a following code snippet written in a file titled "prog_1.php":

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
  ini_set('display_errors',1);
  error_reporting(-1);

  class SimpleClass {
    // property declaration
    public $var = 'a default value';

    // method declaration
    public function displayVar() {
      echo $this->var;
    }
  }

  $instance = new SimpleClass();

  $assigned   =  $instance;
  $reference  =& $instance;
  var_dump($instance);
  echo "\n";
  echo $reference; //At this step I'm getting a "Catchable fatal error" 
  echo "\n";
  var_dump($reference); 
?>
```

My first issue is with the below line from above code :

```
echo $reference;
```

For this code line I'm getting following error :

```
**Catchable fatal error:** Object of class SimpleClass could not be converted to string in /var/www/practice/prog_1.php on line 23
```

I'm not understanding if I could `var_dump()` the object of a class then why can't I echo the same?

My second doubt is if execute following two statements :

```
var_dump($instance);
var_dump($reference);
```

Both the statements given me the same output as follows :

```
object(SimpleClass)#1 (1) {
  ["var"]=>
  string(15) "a default value"
}
```

Why so? Isn't there any difference between object and reference? What does this `#1` mean in above output?

Hope someone could clear my above doubts by providing me satisfactory and best in class answers in a simple, easy to understand and crispy language.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _why can't I echo the same?_  -> see [__toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)

Answer (score 1):

To have a string representation of an object, implement the magic __toString() method in the object. This is used to serialize the object for string representation. (You could use this to return (private) members as a string and make your class "echo-able"

Comment: And to explain your reference question. By reference should be seen as a link using a different variable to the same source variable.

"isn't there any difference between object and reference? " A reference is NOT a data type, it's a method of passing a variable by reference instead of making a copy of it. Can besides objects also be used with strings and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

To echo an object or array you have to use print_r($var); the object or array is not a string and echo only outputs strings integers ..etc